# Construct manifold given simplical complex

Tags: gn.general-topology, simplicial-complexes

It's known that, in general, given a simplical complex, answering if it's homeomorphic to a manifold is [undecidable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex_recognition_problem). However, given a positive answer to the problem, is there an algorithm to construct the manifold as an atlas? Intuitively, given a simplical complex $X$ we can envision something like

1. Let $n$ be the highest dimension present in the complex.
2. For every $v\in V(X)$, $\text{Lk}(X,v)\cong S^{n-1}$. Decidability of this homeomorphism is already taken care of.
3. For every $v\in V(X)$ construct a map $f_v:V(\text{Lk}(X,v))\rightarrow S^{n-1}$, defining a convex polytope in $\mathbb R^n$.
4. Each $f_v$ induces a coordinate patch on the interior of the subcomplex with vertices ${v}\cup V(\text{Lk}(X,v))\subseteq X$ to the interior of the convex polytope by placing $v$ at the origin.
5. Transition maps can be defined piecewise linear for every $n$-simplex, mapping between wedges in the polytopes.

Everything is hazily defined, but besides step 3 none of them look too hard. For manifolds with boundary we might have instances of $D^{n-1}$ as well, but let's not think of that for now.